# SyntaxError in Python decorators

Tags: python, syntax-error, decorator

Why does the following Python code snippet:

```
def f():
    def g():
        def h(x):
            pass
        return h
    return g

@f()()
def i():
    pass
```

raises a `SyntaxError`?

```
    @f()()
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Because as I understanding it, a decorator is a callable with a single required positional parameter, that is to say these are valid decorators:

```
def f(x):
    pass

def g(x, y=3):
    pass

class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        pass

class B:
    def __init__(self, x, y=3):
        pass
```

And they are used as:

```
def h():
    pass

h = f(h)
h = g(h)
h = A(h)
h = B(h)

class C:
    pass

C = f(C)
C = g(C)
C = A(C)
C = B(C)
```

or via the `@expression` statement where `expression` should evaluate to a decorator, and which should be followed by a function or class definition or another `@expression` statement:

```
@f
def h():
    pass

@g
def h():
    pass

@A
def h():
    pass

@B
def h():
    pass

@f
class C:
    pass

@g
class C:
    pass

@A
class C:
    pass

@B
class C:
    pass
```

The following `@expression` statement is perfectly valid:

```
def f():
    def g():
        def h(x):
            pass
        return h
    return g

def g(x):
    def h(x):
        pass
    return g

@g(f()())
def h():
    pass
```

so why the one at the top is not?

Comment: This is a really good question. More telling perhaps is that after your first snippet if you do `z = f()()` then `@z` is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a syntax error, we have to go to the grammar:

```
decorator: '@' dotted_name [ '(' [arglist] ')' ] NEWLINE
```

The part after `@` isn't an arbitrary expression; it's a single name with *one* optional argument list.

I realize this doesn't answer the question of *why* the grammar is written this way, but I don't any answer beyond "That's the way it is".

Comment: I have finally found the reason. It was [Guido's gut feeling](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax).

Comment: Maybe useful for the rationale part "The decorator statement is limited in what it can accept -- arbitrary expressions will not work. Guido preferred this because of a gut feeling [17](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-August/046711.html)." from "PEP 318 -- Decorators for Functions and Methods"

Comment: In the Python-Dev discussion, many people seemed against restricting the `@expression` syntax: "I guess I have the opposite gut feeling: special classes of expressions in the grammar are always bad."

Comment: @Maggyero Guido seems only to be referring to supporting arbitrary expressions, whereas nested function calls could probably be supported with `'@' dotted_name [ ('(' [arglist] ')')* ] NEWLINE`. It's somewhat surprising that the original patch restricted itself to a single argument list (although maybe that makes the grammar no longer LL(1)).

Comment: But Guido did not seeem against lifting that restriction in the future: "I have a gut feeling about this one.  I'm not sure where it comes from, but I have it.  It may be that I want the compiler to be able to recognize certain decorators. So while it would be quite easy to change the syntax to `@test` in the future, I'd like to stick with the more restricted form unless a real use case is presented where allowing `@test` would increase readability. `(@foo().bar()` doesn't count because I don't expect you'll ever need that)."

Comment: I opened an issue in Python Bug Tracker and apparently Guido did not change his mind since 2004: https://bugs.python.org/issue37196.

Comment: I've occasionally observed an ... unwarranted sensitivity towards suggestions to make minor sensible changes. I'd be more satisfied by an answer of "That would be reasonable, but not useful enough to change now" than trying to justify the existing behavior or just rejecting the idea out of hand.